# Extract data from unix server on a specific column on Excel

Tags: excel, unix, putty, vba

I have a requirement where a button click on the Excel spreadsheet calls up putty application and triggers a script on unix server.

This script creates a file with different counts(say abc.txt), example:

```
1
2
5
7
```

Now I want to have another button on spreadsheet when clicked should read abc.txt and copy the outputs on Column E of Sheet 3(Sheet3!E).

Is it possible? If yes then What are my steps?

Comment: I would have the second button run `pscp` (distributed with PuTTY) to copy the file from the server to a local file, open that text file as a worksheet and copy the date from that worksheet to the desired location.

Comment: There are two different questions. Ask them separately. Though I'm pretty sure both are answered here already, if you try searching.

Comment: @AlexP : For that i'll need to setup a password free transmission between user's machine and unix server which means for n users there needs to be n keys installed on unix profile. Is it not possible to pick up the contents of file remotely from the unix server and put them up directly on spreadsheet?